# Android-java Is there a particular functionality to hide class?

Tags: android, jar, apk, reverse, dex

I bought a "Movnowplus" watcher, and I was curious about how my data are treated.

So I made a reverse engineering the following with dex2jar and jd-gui:

https://apkpure.com/movnow-plus/com.veclink.movnow.healthy_q2

I was surprised to see that a lot of activities that I saw in the manifest are not present with jd-gui.

It's normally impossible to hide classes right? Or I miss something?

PS: I checked with adb logcat, and missing activities are well called...

Comment: I believe they use native activities - try [to reverse native libraries](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4632) - probably those that located under assets folder.

Comment: It might be this ( I found in the code of the principal class a  System.loadLibrary call ). Or it can be a packer (packers exist in Android?).

Comment: Absolutely - [check out this great talk](https://youtu.be/vLU92bNeIdI) about some of them.